# Filtro(RowFilter) do DataGridView está dando erro

Tags: c#

**Meu código:**

```
private void txtVendaFiltro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (GridVendas.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("id LIKE '%{0}%'", txtVendaFiltro.Text);
    }
```

**Erro:**

> Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo este post no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328392/cannot-perform-like-operation-on-system-int32-and-system-string-datagridview) você precisa fazer o `cast` desta forma:

```
private void txtVendaFiltro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (GridVendas.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert(id,'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", txtVendaFiltro.Text);
    }
```

O erro acontece porque você está tentando comparar a coluna `int32` do seu `datagrid` com um valor `string`. Fazendo o `cast`, ambos os valores passam a ser strings e a comparação passa a ser possivel usando o `like`.

Comment: funciono, obrigado.